# Search based on user profiles in Drupal 7

Tags: users, search

I want to develop user matching feature on website. A user will search by giving some search criteria (like we give search criteria in dating / real estate website to filter out search results), and system after, filtering out, will return the users matching that search criteria.

How can it be accomplish in Drupal 7 ? Is there any module or combination to modules to achieve that goal ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Searching with Drupal core is not very performative because you are doing search queries in a mysql database.

Apache Solr is much more performative and includes a much greater feature set for searching Drupal content: http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr

If you want to limit search results just to users you can use the solr module above plus Facet API http://drupal.org/project/facetapi and only expose the facets for the content authors. You can also create a view using Solr Views that will return the author in the search results.

Comment: Apache solr is of course a very powerfull search engine. But I think it's way to much work to set-up just to find users.

Comment: Hi BetaRide! Can you please tell what do you suggest as alternative to Solr for things like search users ? thanks

Comment: hi Azeem: I would actually suggest using search_api as suggested by alexis . You can use solr or drupal as a backend. You can create a search specific enitities such as users. Her answer is better!

Answer (score 1):

You can create a view of youe users and expose the desired search criterias. This gives you all you need to search for users. This works even with User defined user fields.

Answer (score 1):

maybe the search api http://drupal.org/project/search_api, and here is the tutorial http://vimeo.com/15556855 about how to setup the api .

i think yo need also http://www.slideshare.net/darrenmothersele/active-tags-and-taxonomy-views-drupal-drop-in-november-2010 here you can find the way to mix taxonomy , views and active tags.